# How do I keep empty levels in bar plot legend when forwarding to ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, bar-chart, ggplotly

If you inspect the `ggplot` output of the code below you will see that all three groups are present in the legend thanks to `drop = FALSE`. However, when forwarding this to `ggplotly()` the empty level is no longer there. How do I keep it?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# data
df <- data.frame(type = factor(c("kiwi", "banana"),
                               levels = c("kiwi", "banana", "apple")),
                 count = c(1, 3))

# ggplot
ggp <- ggplot(df, aes(y = count, fill = type, x = "a_bar")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("forestgreen", "gold1", "firebrick"),
                    drop = FALSE)

# ggplotly 
ggplotly(ggp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be using `plotly_build` to have access to the layers of your plot. After that, you copy one layer (in this case kiwi or banana) and change the argument like name, legendgroup, color, and y coordinates, and `append` this created layer back to the object. After that, you can plot it again and you will the see apple in your legend. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
# data
df <- data.frame(type = factor(c("kiwi", "banana"),
                               levels = c("kiwi", "banana", "apple")),
                 count = c(1, 3))

# ggplot
ggp <- ggplot(df, aes(y = count, fill = type, x = "a_bar")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("forestgreen", "gold1", "firebrick"),
                    drop = FALSE)
# ggplotly 
p <- ggplotly(ggp)
x <- plotly_build(p)
g <- list(x$x$data[[2]])
g[[1]]$name <- 'apple'
g[[1]]$legendgroup <- 'apple'
g[[1]]$showlegend <- TRUE
g[[1]]$marker$color <- 'firebrick'
g[[1]]$y <- 0
x$x$data <- append(x$x$data, g)
x
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>